# how to check the condition before the sequence container runs, in ssis 2005?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I need to split my DB into two DB's as current and History in SSIS,and i need to split only the 5 fact tables in single package.So I have taken 5 data flow tasks for 5 tables in a sequence container.Now I want to run it after satisfying my condition(splitting must be done at starting day of the every year from current DB to History DB i.e,. after completing this year the previous year data must go to history DB automatically by running it) i.e., it should run every year at January 1st. So what task could i need to put before the sequence container and in what way do i need to put the query into that task?

```
       Please reply me as early as possible, I'm waiting for the response.
```

Comment: Cant you accomplish the logic with a SQL statement and use an execute SQL task?

Comment: i have tried like giving the condition in execute sql task as " if(month(getdate)=01 and day(getdate()=01)" but i'm unable to understand that after this condition is satisfied i would like to goto sequence container, so i would like to know how the query could be continued.......

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean Package variable e.g. StartSequenceContainer.

Use a similar query in your execute SQL task -

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (Month(GetDate()) =1 AND Day(GetDate()) = 1) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS StartSequenceContainer
```

Store the result of the query in the variable by selecting Single row as result set and configure the results table in the Execute SQL Task.
[image]

In the Precedence path between the Execute SQL task and Sequence Container, set it to Expression and Constraint. In the expression set it to the boolean variable StartSequenceContainer.

Comment: Thank you for giving us the good info, it is working but it showing some error like "parameter name is unrecognised.. and result set property not set correctly......."

Comment: How have you mapped the result set? Is the Resultset property set to single row? I will add some screenshots

Comment: Yes , I have mapped the result set to single row.But still it is showing the error as previous one, " [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "select case when month(getdate())=01 and day(getda..." failed with the following error: "Parameter name is unrecognized.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
This is the error shown in progress tab

Comment: Do you have any parameters mapped?

Comment: Yes I have mapped a output parameter as Var with long datatype

Comment: what is that for? The result from the query SELECT CASE WHEN (Month(GetDate()) =1 AND Day(GetDate()) = 1) THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS StartSequenceContainer would be set in the ResultSet screen as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: ok i have removed that but no use it is not checking the condition i needed. that means the complete package is running without checking with the month and day of getdate

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of how you have set your precedence constraint?